# Sonata - How to create filter on dynamic property?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

Into Sonata, I have a Booking Admin.

In this Admin I have some field stored into database like "lastname", "firstname" or "ref". I also have a field "status" which is non DB stored it's defined like this in my Booking Entity.

```
    public function getState(){
        if (/*Complex condition*/)
          return 'canceled_not_refund';
        else if (/*Complex condition*/)
          return 'canceled';
        else if (/*Complex condition*/)
          return "no-payment";
        else if (/*Complex condition*/)
          return "partial_payment";
        else if (/*Complex condition*/)
          return "ok";
        else if(/*Complex condition*/)
          return "ended";
      }
```

I tried to define a filter on "state" field but I get:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 87 near 'state = :sta': Error: Class MyBundle\Entity\Booking has no field or association named state

Is there a way to define this kind of filter into Sonata Admin?

Thks for help!

Comment: I don’t see any way. Sonata would have to load all entities into memory and filter them. All [filter methods](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/filter_field_definition.html#filter-field-definition) work with a QueryBuilder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Lumen already commented, all the filters work with the QueryBuilder, so trying to directly filter on something that is not in the database, is not possible.

Assuming that the `complex condition` you're talking about only contain fields that are in the database, you could do something like this:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper 
$datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('status', 'doctrine_orm_callback', array(
            'label' => 'Payment Status',
            'callback' => function($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value) {
                if ($value['value'] == 'canceled_not_refund') {

                    $queryBuilder->andWhere($alias . '.columnA = :some_value');
                    $queryBuilder->andWhere($alias . '.columnB = :other_value');
                    $queryBuilder->setParameter('some_value', 'some');
                    $queryBuilder->setParameter('other_value', 'other');

                } elseif ($value['value'] == 'canceled') {

                    $queryBuilder->andWhere($alias . '.columnA = :some_value');
                    $queryBuilder->andWhere($alias . '.columnB = :other_value');
                    $queryBuilder->setParameter('some_value', 'some');
                    $queryBuilder->setParameter('other_value', 'other');

                }

            }
            ), 'choice', array('choices' => array(
                   ''    => '', // Empty option to not filter anything
                   'canceled_not_refund' => 'Canceled without refund', 
                   'canceled'  => 'Canceled'),  
        ));
}
```

Of course you can move the callback to a separate function to make the code a bit cleaner.

A big disadvantage of this, is that you get a bit of code duplication, so if your logic changes for determining the status, it needs to be changed on 2 places.

Please note that in the queryBuilder you need the `$alias` to make sure you select from the right table.